# How to use php's exec function to start a nodejs process

Tags: php, exec

I need to remotely restart the nodejs site on the server via php. It's easy to end this nodejs process, but I can't start it because of lifecycle issues. What should I do about this?
The following code is an api that can be accessed over the network to implement lookup and end nodejs.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$cmd = 'netstat -aon|findstr "0.0.0.0:8888"';
echo 'C:\Users\Server>'.$cmd."\n";
exec($cmd,$out);
if(!empty($out)){
    echo $out[0]."\n";
    $pid = explode(" ",$out[0]);
    $pid = intval(end($pid));
    if($pid>20){
        $cmd = 'taskkill /f /pid '.$pid;
        echo 'C:\Users\Server>'.$cmd."\n";
        exec($cmd,$out);
        echo "killed\n";
    }
}else{
    echo "notfind 8888\n";
}
$cmd = 'cmd /c E:\nodejs\run.bat';
echo 'C:\Users\Server>'.$cmd."\n";
exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a exe user c#. use exec function

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace run
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"node.exe", @"E:\nodejs\index.js");

        }
    }
}
```